They c’n go loose and rape up the countryside for all of ‘em who run this county care
In the book "To Kill a Mockingbird" there is a sentence I'm not sure I understand. It's uttered by one of the inhabitants of Maycomb (the town where the main characters of the book live). The sentence is overheard by the children of a defense attorney of a black man accused of rape.

“They c’n go loose and rape up the countryside for all of ‘em who run
this county care,”

does "go" mean..

to be or continue to be in a specified state or condition: to go in rags; to go in poverty. (Collins Dictionary)

and "loose"...

Free from confinement or imprisonment; unfettered: criminals loose in the neighborhood; dogs that are loose on the streets.(American Heritage Dictionary)

..?
Also: Shouldn't it be "for all ‘em who run this county care,” and not "for all of 'em who run this county care,"? After all it's "for all I care" and not "for all of I care"

It's a partitive construction there, and would need a plural pronoun in the objective case, not "all of I". You could say "The damn library can burn down, for all of us care!" as a non-standard variant of "for all we care".

The sentence you are reading is a direct quote from an uneducated, possibly illiterate, person. It is not an example of good grammar.
"Go" here means to become, as in "go wild" or "go crazy".
"Loose" means what you think; unrestricted, unrestrained, unfettered.
The "of" you are talking about should be omitted by a person using correct grammar, but the mistake is a common one, conflating similar phrases: e.g. "all of those who run the country are careless". Note also that "em" is short for "them" which is also wrong and should be "those". But the phrasing written would get common.

I think "don't care" would be closer to the intended meaning than "are careless"

I didn't mean that to be an equivalent sentence. I wanted a correct sentence, and I wanted to avoidvthe almost-double-negative of "don't care".

I note though, @DJClayworth, that your characterizations “not an example of good grammar” and “mistake” and “wrong” and “should be” are all thoroughly prescriptive. While a major function of ELL is to help learners acquire the standard dialects of English, one can do so without denigrating other dialects. The only criterion for what constitutes valid English is what communities of speakers actually do say.

This seems a caricature of uneducated English put in the mouth of a character meant to be unsympathetic, and is probably deliberately ungrammatical; I wouldn't take it as an accurate representation of working-class rural southern American English. Ugly morals, ugly speech, ugly appearance are all conflated by writers.

@StuartF It is exactly the sort of rhetoric that played out in the last presidential election here in the States, this time with respect to immigrants, and it is a realistic picture of the racism in the US South (and elsewhere) in the 1930s, not an exaggeration or distorted caricature at all. Even as late as the mid 1970s, just twenty miles north of Atlanta, you could turn off the main road onto a smaller spur road and be greeted by a huge billboard that said "Welcome to Klan Country". I know this firsthand

Here's an example of such a billboard: https://davidcecelski.com/2017/09/14/the-klan-last-time-part-5-welcome-to-smithfield/
